# sed returning different result on different platforms

Tags: linux, sed, embedded, embedded-linux

Hi using following command on an x86 machine (using /bin/sh) returns: `<port>3<port>`

```
test="port 3"
echo $test | sed -r 's/\s*port\s*([0-9]+)\s*/<port>\1<\/port>/'
```

but running same command on sh shell of an ARM based network switch returns the string `port 3`.

How can I get same result on switch as I got on my x86 machine? To me it seems like digit is not being captured by [0-9].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\s` is a GNU sed extension to the standard sed behavior. GNU sed is the implementation on desktop/server Linux systems. Most embedded Linux systems run [BusyBox](http://busybox.net/), a suite of utilities with a markedly smaller footprint and fewer features.

A standard way of specifying “any space character” is the `[:space:]` [character class](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05). It is supported by BusyBox (at least, by most BusyBox installations; most BusyBox features can be stripped off for an even lower footprint).

BusyBox also doesn't support the `-r` option, you need to use a [basic regular expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03). In a BRE, `\(…\)` marks groups, and there is no `+` operator, only `*`.

```
echo "$test" | sed 's/[[:space:]]*port[[:space:]]*\([0-9][0-9]*\)[[:space:]]*/<port>\1<\/port>/'
```

Note that since you didn't put any quotes around `$test`, the shell performed word splitting and wildcard expansion on the value of the variable. That is, the value of the variable was treated as a whitespace-separated list of file names which were then joined by a single space. So if you leave out the quotes, you don't have to worry about different kinds of whitespace, you can write `echo $test | sed 's/ *port *([0-9][0-9]*) */<port>\1<\/port>/'`. However, if `$test` had been `port *`, the result would have depended on what files exist in the current directory.

Comment: Thank you Gilles for detailed response.

Answer (score 3):

Not all seds support reg-expression short-hand like `\s`. A more portable version is

```
  test="port 3"
  echo "$test" | sed -r 's/[ ]*port[ ]*([0-9]+)[ ]*/<port>\1<\/port>/'
```

If you really need to check for tab chars as well, just add them to the char class (in all 3 places) that, in my example just contain space chars, i.e. the `[ ]` bit.

**output**

```
<port>3</port>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: baltusaj : Thanks I'm glad that helped. I would recommend that you accept @Giles answer, as it does a better in explaining the solution AND it is also better to use `[:space:]`, assuming your system supports it (most do). Good luck to all.

Comment: You were the first one to answer but still upon your recommendation accepted the Giles' answer.

Comment: @baltusaj :   glad to have been of service. I know when I write an better explanation that doesn't get accepted, I don't like it, so I'm happy to share the rep points with a better answer. Good luck.